# Locating element by id command works in Selenium ide but not in Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver, selenium-ide

I had an issue trying to locate a dropdown box.  I got it to work with an absolute path but not with the actual xpath or id of the element.  It is super frustrating and just cant figure it out.

I installed Selenium IDE to see if it would work there and selenium IDE picks up the dropdown box.  I exported this test to JAVA/JUNIT and copied and pasted the command I needed into my existing test.  The command which worked in Selenium id was:

```
Command: select
Target: id=z_be
Value: label=All conditions must be met
```

I exported this to java:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("z_be"))).selectByVisibleText("All conditions must be met");
```

but I get the error:

```
UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"
```

This issue is driving me crazy and would love it if someone can point me in the right direction and show me the errors of my ways.  The html is:

```
<select id="z_be" class="vui-input d2l-select" name="z_be" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<option value="1">All conditions must be met</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Any condition must be met</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is the id `z_be` unique? i guess some other div element is also sharing the same id.

Comment: Hi Sudharsan Selvaraj,  I see only a few instances of this z_be:  <label id="ctl_41" class="vui-label" for="z_be">
<span>To access this item, users must satisfy</span>
</label>  the other is n the middle of some hugh html chunk: <input name="d2l_controlMap" value="[{'btn_publish': ... Checkbox',[1,1],{},0,1], ...

Comment: Run `document.querySelectorAll("#z_be").length` in the dev console... does it return 1?

Comment: @JeffC Hi Jeff I ran the command in the firefox console and it returns 1

Comment: That means that the id z_be is unique on the page. It should be safe to use that as a locator. From the error message, it looks like that id belongs to a DIV and not to a SELECT as you thought. You'll have to do some more investigating.

Comment: @Jeff I tried the following had no success:  WebElement myoption = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#z_be option[value='1']"));
 myoption.click();

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working.  I tried the following but it didn't work which i dont know why as it successfully identified it in firebug css:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id*='z_be'] option[value='1']")).click();
```

But then I tried this and it did work:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value='2']")).click();
```